# Iphone Picker with Array from URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, uiactionsheet, picker

```
-(void)dismissActionSheet:(id)sender {
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction) pressButton:(id)sender{



actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);



UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
pickerView.dataSource = pickerArray;
pickerView.delegate = self;

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
[pickerView release];

UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"OK"]];
closeButton.momentary = YES; 
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

[closeButton release];

[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

[actionSheet release];
}
```

I have made a picker that pops up like a keyboard with the press of a button.
Now I am just trying to populate it with an array from my site.
i.e. http://www.mywebsite.com/app/array.txt

This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tntmax.com/app/gQL420pt.txt"];
NSString *x = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
self.pickerArray = x;

[x release];
```

It doesn't seem to work.
I have tried many different ways, this just being the most recent try.

The page on my website looks like this:

```
@"object1", @"thing2", @"person3", @"stuff4", nil
```

I can change the format of the text to what ever would work best for the code. Let me know.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [UIPickerView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html). You can't use an `NSString` as the datasouce, instead your need an object that conforms to the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol.

Also, if you're trying to load an `NSArray` from your website you can format the data as a plist, and then use `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url]`. This will give you data that's more suited to be used by the `UIPickerViewDataSource`

```
// plist header here (look it up...)
<plist>
<array>
    <string>object1</string>
    <string>thing1</string>
    // more strings
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tntmax.com/app/gQL420pt.txt"];
   NSString *reply= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
   NSArray *txtItems= [reply componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   //if u want remove @"" from all values then replace items in array withReplacingocurrenceOfString with @ and "
   self.pickerArray = txtItems; // as pickerArray is nsarray if not(nsmutableArray) then use [txtItems mutableCopy];
 }
```